# tshark piping output results in packet counter

Tags: tshark

When I try to pipe tshark output to anything I cannot see the traffic any longer. Tshark just shows a packet counter. How can I prevent this?

```
 sudo tshark -i enp60s0 -f "tcp" -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.checksum -e tcp.options -E header=y | column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Context

For context, this is the command and output you are talking about:

```
$ sudo tshark -i enp60s0 -f "tcp" -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport \
    -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.checksum -e tcp.options -E header=y | column -t
Capturing on 'Eth: enp60s0'
45
```

Tshark will send control information like where it's capturing and the packet count to stderr instead of stdout. If you don't want to see this control information, send stderr to dev null:

```
$ sudo tshark ... 2>/dev/null | column -t
```

#### Method

We can also continuously generate a new capture every second that we can then read with tshark (see tshark's [manpage](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for full details). This is similar to @ChristopherMaynard's solution, but you don't need to wait for the capture to finish. Saving (`-w`) with the `-b duration:1` will save a new capture every second:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo tshark -w temp.pcap -b duration:1 2>/dev/null &

i=0
while true
  do if [ "$i" != "$(ls -1A . | wc -l)" ]; then 
    newfile="$(ls -t | head -n1)"
    sudo tshark -r "$newfile" 2>/dev/null | column -t
  fi  
  sleep 0.1 
done
```

#### Verification

Running this, we get output like below. Note that we are reading new packet captures, so tshark adds numbers starting at 1 for each new capture it's reading.

```
1   0.000000  192.168.2.1    →  192.168.2.242    DNS      134  Standard     query  response           0xfd75             No                            such                         name               PTR                                     1.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa      SOA                localhost               6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7  ←  78:8a:20:d9:f9:11
2   0.000412  192.168.2.242  →  192.168.2.1      DNS      87   Standard     query  0x2a9b             PTR                249.249.16.104.in-addr.arpa   78:8a:20:0d:05:e7            ←                  6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
3   0.023726  192.168.2.1    →  192.168.2.242    DNS      149  Standard     query  response           0x2a9b             No                            such                         name               PTR                                     249.249.16.104.in-addr.arpa   SOA                cruz.ns.cloudflare.com  6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7  ←  78:8a:20:d9:f9:11
4   0.024091  192.168.2.242  →  192.168.2.1      DNS      85   Standard     query  0x2f71             PTR                40.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa     78:8a:20:0d:05:e7            ←                  6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
1   1.026460  192.168.2.242  →  192.168.2.255    UDP      86   57621        →      57621              Len=44             ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff             ←                            6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
2   1.048071  192.168.2.1    →  192.168.2.242    DNS      135  Standard     query  response           0x2f71             No                            such                         name               PTR                                     40.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa     SOA                localhost               6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7  ←  78:8a:20:d9:f9:11
3   1.048555  192.168.2.242  →  192.168.2.1      DNS      87   Standard     query  0xe77d             PTR                25.206.252.198.in-addr.arpa   78:8a:20:0d:05:e7            ←                  6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
4   1.125073  192.168.2.1    →  192.168.2.242    DNS      118  Standard     query  response           0xe77d             PTR                           25.206.252.198.in-addr.arpa  PTR                stackoverflow.com                       6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7             ←                  78:8a:20:d9:f9:11
```

Answer (score 0):

The `column` command needs to read all of the input in order to decide how wide to make each column, so you can't use `column` in this context.  (You can test this by issuing your `tshark` command and then elsewhere issuing a `killall tshark` and you will then see all your output.

Instead, I think you will have to redirect your output to a file and then once you're finished your `tshark` capture session, you can `cat file | column -t` if you want.  If you want to see the output on the screen as well as redirect it to a file for later processing, you can pipe it to `tee` and provide `tee` with the name of the file to write to.  For example, `tshark [options] | tee file`, but the output you see won't be as nicely formatted until you later do `cat file | column -t`.